# bisect_left returns different values for the same arguments

Tags: python

I am calling bisect_left twice, like that:

```
index = bisect_left([0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04,0.05],0.05)
```

Once I get `index=4`, and once `index=5`.
Did anyone encounter this bug?
Thanks
R.D.

Comment: [mcve] please...

Comment: Are you using python 2 or python 3?

Comment: I tested it 10 times and it always gives `4`.

Comment: if your `0.05` is the result of another operation (and not a constant), that could explain it...

Comment: Now I tested it 10M times, still always gives 4.

Comment: It is indeed probably due to rounding errors with floating points.

Comment: Thanks, you were right. it happend due to the rounding error.